# K-fold in Python

Tags: python

Given a large dataframe for which I an running a 5-fold cross-validation, how would I store each fold in a train and test array.

See scikit-learn documentation here:  http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/cross_validation.html

Here is the example they gave:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> from sklearn.model_selection import KFold

>>> X = ["a", "b", "c", "d"]
>>> kf = KFold(n_splits=2)
>>> for train, test in kf.split(X):
...     print("%s %s" % (train, test))
[2 3] [0 1]
[0 1] [2 3]

Each fold is constituted by two arrays: the first one is related to the training set, and the second one to the test set. Thus, one can create the training/test sets using numpy indexing:

>>>
>>> X = np.array([[0., 0.], [1., 1.], [-1., -1.], [2., 2.]])
>>> y = np.array([0, 1, 0, 1])
>>> X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = X[train], X[test], y[train], y[test]
```

My dataframe has thousands of values, but I would like to store the values like so:

V_train, V_test, W_train, W_test, X_train, X_test, Y_train, Y_test, Z_train, Z_test

Comment: ... I'm sorry, what is your question? That code demonstrates how to do this. Just loop over your folds and store the results in some container.

Comment: I am beginner when it come to programming, so I know what I need to do, but I don't know how to do it programatically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do following:

```
X = pd.DataFrame() # here should be your initial DataFrame with more than 5 rows
kf = KFold(n_splits=5)

((V_train_ids, V_test_ids), 
 (W_train_ids, W_test_ids),
 (X_train_ids, X_test_ids), 
 (Y_train_ids, Y_test_ids), 
 (Z_train_ids, Z_test_ids)) = list(kf.split(X))
```

EDIT:

After that, you get indices of train and test parts of specified fold. To get train and test object, you can access them by this indices:

```
((V_train, V_test), 
 (W_train, W_test),
 (X_train, X_test), 
 (Y_train, Y_test), 
 (Z_train, Z_test)) = ((X[V_train_ids], X[V_test_ids]),
                       (X[W_train_ids], X[W_test_ids]),
                       (X[X_train_ids], X[X_test_ids]),
                       (X[Y_train_ids], X[Y_test_ids]),
                       (X[Z_train_ids], X[Z_test_ids]))
```